# My Sudoku checker returns the wrong boolean value - it correctly returns false when invalid but not true when valid

Tags: javascript

I am on a final project of a beginner intro course to coding - for the life of me I can't figure out why my checker will not return true when valid, but it will return false when invalid.

I'm a beginner so you'll have to bare with me if the answer is glaringly obvious but at this point I feel like I've just been staring at a screen for the past hour trying to figure it out.

```js
//puzzle
let puzzle = [[ 8,9,5,   7,4,2,   1,3,6 ],
              [ 2,7,1,   9,6,3,   4,8,5 ],
              [ 4,6,3,   5,8,1,   7,9,2 ],

              [ 9,3,4,   6,1,7,   2,5,8 ],
              [ 5,1,7,   2,3,8,   9,6,4 ],
              [ 6,8,2,   4,5,9,   3,7,1 ],

              [ 1,5,9,   8,7,4,   6,2,3 ],
              [ 7,4,6,   3,2,5,   8,1,9 ],
              [ 3,2,8,   1,9,6,   5,4,7 ]];


//puzzle 2
let puzzleTwo = [[ 8,9,5,7,4,2,1,3,6 ],
                [ 8,7,1,9,6,3,4,8,5 ],
                [ 4,6,3,5,8,1,7,9,2 ],
                [ 9,3,4,6,1,7,2,5,8 ],
                [ 5,1,7,2,3,8,9,6,4 ],
                [ 6,8,2,4,5,9,3,7,1 ],
                [ 1,5,9,8,7,4,6,2,3 ],
                [ 7,4,6,3,2,5,8,1,9 ],
                [ 3,2,8,1,9,6,5,4,7 ]];

//DO NOT EDIT ABOVE

function getRow(puzzle, row) {
    // YOUR CODE
    return puzzle[row];                              
}

function getColumn(puzzle, col) {
    // YOUR CODE
    let column = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < puzzle.length; i++) {
        column.push(puzzle[i][col]);
    }
    return column;
}

function getSection(puzzle, x, y) {
    // YOUR CODE
    let numSubgrid = [];
    x *= 3;
    y *= 3;
    for (let i = y; i < y + 3; i++) {
        for (let j = x; j < x + 3; j++) {
            numSubgrid.push(puzzle[i][j])
        }
    }
    return numSubgrid;
}

function includes1To9(arr) {
    // YOUR CODE
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (i !== j && arr[i] === arr[j]) {
                return false;
            } 
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function sudokuIsValid(puzzle) {
    // YOUR CODE
    if (includes1To9(getRow) || includes1To9(getColumn) || includes1To9(getSection) !== true) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones `getRow` is defined. It is a function in global scope.

Comment: Your code has multiple bugs. `if (includes1To9(getRow) || includes1To9(getColumn) || includes1To9(getSection) !== true)` does not what you expect. `includes1To9(getRow)` calls a function and passes a function as argument, but `function includes1To9(arr)` expects an array as argument. But I have great news for you. You don't have to ask others to find bugs in your code. You can run your code in your debugger and step line by line through the code and compare the expected behavior with the actual behavior.

Comment: @jabaa fair, I guess I meant it's a function and not a variable, so passing `getRow` and expecting `includes1To9` to accept an array is why it isn't working.

Comment: @Cluff3rs I'd recommend adding some breakpoints or `console.log` statements to see how your code is executing.

Answer (score 0):

`includes1To9()` is expecting an array to be passed as a parameter, but you're currently passing `getRow`, which is a function.

So in `sudokuIsValid()` iterate over the rows/cols and call `getRow(i)` (and `getCol(i)`), and then pass that array to `includes1To9()`.

Then, because `getSection` is defined with x,y coordinates you'll need to iterate over that separately from (0,0) to (2,2).

My last suggestion is to use debugging statements (`console.log()` is the most common) or [breakpoints in a debugging tool](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/breakpoints/) to inspect code as it's executing, to verify each step does what you're expecting.

```js
//puzzle
let puzzle = [[ 8,9,5,   7,4,2,   1,3,6 ],
              [ 2,7,1,   9,6,3,   4,8,5 ],
              [ 4,6,3,   5,8,1,   7,9,2 ],

              [ 9,3,4,   6,1,7,   2,5,8 ],
              [ 5,1,7,   2,3,8,   9,6,4 ],
              [ 6,8,2,   4,5,9,   3,7,1 ],

              [ 1,5,9,   8,7,4,   6,2,3 ],
              [ 7,4,6,   3,2,5,   8,1,9 ],
              [ 3,2,8,   1,9,6,   5,4,7 ]];


//puzzle 2
let puzzleTwo = [[ 8,9,5,7,4,2,1,3,6 ],
                [ 8,7,1,9,6,3,4,8,5 ],
                [ 4,6,3,5,8,1,7,9,2 ],
                [ 9,3,4,6,1,7,2,5,8 ],
                [ 5,1,7,2,3,8,9,6,4 ],
                [ 6,8,2,4,5,9,3,7,1 ],
                [ 1,5,9,8,7,4,6,2,3 ],
                [ 7,4,6,3,2,5,8,1,9 ],
                [ 3,2,8,1,9,6,5,4,7 ]];

//DO NOT EDIT ABOVE

function getRow(puzzle, row) {
    // YOUR CODE
    return puzzle[row];                              
}

function getColumn(puzzle, col) {
    // YOUR CODE
    let column = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < puzzle.length; i++) {
        column.push(puzzle[i][col]);
    }
    return column;
}

function getSection(puzzle, x, y) {
    // YOUR CODE
    let numSubgrid = [];
    x *= 3;
    y *= 3;
    for (let i = y; i < y + 3; i++) {
        for (let j = x; j < x + 3; j++) {
            numSubgrid.push(puzzle[i][j])
        }
    }
    return numSubgrid;
}

function includes1To9(arr) {
    // YOUR CODE
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (i !== j && arr[i] === arr[j]) {
                return false;
            } 
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function sudokuIsValid(puzzle) {
    // YOUR CODE

    // check each row and column, indexes 0-8
    for (let i=0; i<puzzle.length; i++) {
      let row = getRow(puzzle, i);
      let col = getColumn(puzzle, i);
      
      console.log(row);
      console.log(includes1To9(row));
      
      console.log(col);
      console.log(includes1To9(col));
      
      if (!includes1To9(row) || !includes1To9(col))     
      {
        return false;
      }
    }
    
    // check each section, coordinates (0,0) to (2,2)
    for (let i=0; i<3; i++) {
      for (let j=0; j<3; j++) {
        let section = getSection(puzzle, i, j);
        
        console.log(section);
        console.log(includes1To9(section));
        
        if (!includes1To9(section))
        {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
    
    return true;
}

console.log(sudokuIsValid(puzzle));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's your last function `sudokuIsValid()` that is the issue. In it, in the condition for your `if` statement, you call the function `includes1To9()` on other *functions* instead of lists representing rows, columns, and sections like you want it to. You need to call `getRow()`, `getColumn()`, and `getSection()` on all rows, columns, and sections and then call `includes1To9()` on each of them. The below code is one way you could do that:

```
function sudokuIsValid(puzzle) {
    for (let i=0; i < puzzle.length; i++) {
        if (includes1To9(getRow(puzzle,i))==False || includes1To9(getColumn(puzzle,i))==False {
            return False
        }
    for (let i=0; i < 3, i++) {
        for (let n=0; n < 3; n++) {
            if (includes1To9(getSection(puzzle,i,n))==False) {
                return False
            }
        }
    }
    return True
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that right after I posted it - just edited it though, so it should be good now. Technically you don't have to make a separate loop though - `getSection(puzzle,Math.floor(i/3),i%3)` would also have worked. I didn't use that though because I wanted my answer to be as plain and simple as possible